# Getting duplicated notification in app with deleted notification tiltle

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am getting a weird output while debugging my app. At the first, when I run the app the notification title at the time of alarm is as per the code below i.e Dosing Alert!:

```
    String banner="Time to dose your "+AType;

    NotificationHelper notificationHelper=new NotificationHelper(this);
    NotificationCompat.Builder 
    nb=notificationHelper.getChannel1Notification("Dosing Alert!",banner);
    notificationHelper.getManager().notify(1,nb.build());
```

But after that I am getting 2 notifications. One with title "Dosing Alert!" and another one with title "Dosing Alert" (exclamation missing.. this title was set by me in the beginning but later I added an exclamation). I searched everywhere for this issue but couldn't understand why this is happening.

This is my notification helper class.

```
public class NotificationHelper extends ContextWrapper {
public static  final String channel1ID="channel1ID";
public static  final String channel1IName="Just Plant Them";
private NotificationManager mManager;
public NotificationHelper(Context base) {
    super(base);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        createChannels();
    }

}
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public void createChannels() {
    NotificationChannel channel1 = new NotificationChannel(channel1ID, channel1IName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    channel1.enableLights(true);
    channel1.enableVibration(true);
    channel1.setLightColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
    channel1.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
    getManager().createNotificationChannel(channel1);
       }

public NotificationManager getManager() {
    if (mManager==null){
        mManager=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }
    return mManager;
}
public NotificationCompat.Builder getChannel1Notification(String title,String message){
    return new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),channel1ID)

            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.plant)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);


}
```

}

Please help me with a solution.

Comment: Okay so I found a solution accidently and I realized how stupid I was. I implemented a notification somewhere else as well with title "Dosing alert". My bad.